# Application not covering the whole screen on IPad

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, fullscreen

I recently developed an application that was supposed to only run on iPhone but i could not find anywhere to make it not be usable for iPad users. So i thought i will try to fix the problem instead.

When running on iPad, the screen is not covered. It looks like this:

[image]

That is the bottom of the screen but its the same for the top.

I also added these images since i think i read somwhere that its needed. I used assset catalog creator:

What can i do to fix this problem? Also if you have any ideas on how to disable it for iPad users please write that also as it would be good to know that for future cases.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: You would generally have a different storyboard for iPhone and iPad.  There is lots of documentation about supporting iPad on Apple's Developer site; what have you read so far?

Comment: Different storyboards? No, Im using universal sizes on my starboards meaning it should be able to fit every screen just by using one storyboard. 

I have set neccessary constraints also. Looking at the preview everything looks good. But as soon as i launch it for ipad. It does not cover the whole screen @Droppy

Answer (score 1):

Set the deployment target to universal fixed this issue for me

Target >> General >> Deployment Info >> Deployment Target

Choose "Universal"

[image: deployment_target_screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

> Also if you have any ideas on how to disable it for iPad users

You cannot "disable it for iPad users". If your app runs on iPhone, it will run on iPad. It might run as an iPhone app in the iPad's "emulator" mode, but it will run, and you cannot prevent it.

The alternative is to make this a Universal app and have it run *natively* on the iPad.